# ngDialog Close Button redirect To other page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing application using AngularJs for popup i am using ngDialog.
One of my requirement is.Once we close the ngDialog popup.I need to redirect the current page to home page.

My code :

```
ngDialog.open({
                template:'<div style="margin-top:10px;" >Please try after some time.</div>',
                plain:true,
                closeByEscape : false,
                closeByDocument : false
            });
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hei, you can try to use the preCloseCallback in order to redirect to your desired page (home page). For this you'll need $window as injection and you can use it like this :

```
preCloseCallback: function(value) {
       var url = "#/home" // or whatever the route is
       $window.location = url
       return true
     }
```

Hope it'll help. Best!

Comment: Hi, I used this code this will success fully redirect to home page.But the popup is not closing after page redirect..

Comment: Try the alternative closeThisDialog function, I think you can get the desired behaviour by using only this. trial and error now :D

Comment: How can i use closeThisDialog  function ngDialog? Can u give one example

Comment: I've edited the answer so you return true in the preCloseCallback, it should work now.

Comment: please mark it as correct so other users know they can use this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dialog = ngDialog.open({
    template: 'templateId'
});

dialog.closePromise.then(function (data) {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```